# how to diagnose why program hangs due `lock` statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

In the code below when I uncomment commented code my program has incorrect behavior.

```
    private void RecalculateOrders(bool force)
    {
        //if (force)
        //{
        //    lock (desiredOrdersBuy)
        //    {
        //        RecalculateOrdersInternal();
        //    }
        //}
        //else
        //{
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(desiredOrdersBuy))
            {
                try
                {
                    RecalculateOrdersInternal();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(desiredOrdersBuy);
                }
            }
        //}
    }
```

I do not understand how to diagnose what exactly is wrong. How can I know how `lock` statement affects my program? If I have dead-lock then how can I catch it? What would you do to find why `lock` breaks execution?

Comment: Are you saying that `Monitor.TryEnter` works but `lock` creates a deadlock?

Comment: `Monitor.TryEnter` works but `lock` doesn't work (program behavior is incorrect, it kind of hangs) i'm not sure if this is a dead-lock, but it might be.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, to diagnose this issue you're going to want to use the `Threads` window when debugging. This will allow you to switch between running threads and see where each thread is. Clearly another thread has an exclusive lock on this object and if you place a breakpoint on the `lock` statement and look at the other `Threads` **before** trying to execute the `lock` statement I'm sure you'll find another thread locking that object.

**NOTE:** to open the Threads window your application actually has to be running.

Now, to clarify the differences between `Monitor.TryEnter` and `lock`, per the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx), `Monitor.TryEnter` is most certainly different:

> If successful, this method acquires an exclusive lock on the obj parameter. This method returns immediately, whether or not the lock is available.
>
> This method is similar to Enter, but it will never block. If the thread cannot enter without blocking, the method returns false, and the thread does not enter the critical section.

So, that is why `lock` produces a deadlock but `Monitor.TryEnter` doesn't.

Comment: it's really hard to debug HFT application, but i can add "tracing"... probably each time i'm going to `lock (desiredOrdersBuy)` i should just `Console.Writeln`, then i will probably find a dead-lock....

Answer (score 0):

```
lock (desiredOrdersBuy)
{
    RecalculateOrdersInternal();
}
```

and

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(desiredOrdersBuy))
{
    try
    {
        RecalculateOrdersInternal();
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(desiredOrdersBuy);
    }
}
```

does the same thing. lock(){} is Syntactic sugar ofr Monitor.Enter/Exit.

Your problem is that in commented code you aditionally check `if(force)` condition.

Comment: i'm using `Monitor.TryEnter` not `Monitor.Enter`

Comment: That's incorrect. Lock uses Monitor.Enter, not TryEnter.